# How can I create more than one Model in a view? Preferably using Partial Views and a dynamic number of models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have list of "skills" that I want a user to be able to go through, selecting appropriate levels from the list.  So Skill looks something like this:

```
public class Skill
{
    public String SkillName { get; set; }
    public SkillLevel CurrentSkillLevel { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsRequired { get; set; }

    public Skill(String Name)
    {
        this.SkillName = Name;
        this.IsRequired = true;
        this.CurrentSkillLevel = SkillLevel.None;
    }
}
```

There could be hundreds of skills - and the exact number is unknown at the moment, and certainly it needs to be dynamic, so I don't want to make the user go through the process of clicking on each skill, filling out the form, and submitting each time.  I'd like to display all of the skills in the same page (one row each), allow the user to select all the values, then click submit once at the end.

Unfortunately, I've not had any experience with using MVC for anything other than singleton creation.  I would normally use a separate ViewModel for several models bundled together, but I don't see how that would work with a dynamic list, and since they are all the same type ("Skill"), I guess the ViewModel would look exactly like a list of the model.

Does anyone have an appropriate solution?

Thanks

Comment: I honestly don't know how to bind this. Clearly recursion is called for. But how to maintain such relationships... I'm struggling. Answer I gave works for simple array...

Answer (score 1):

Building on DaveA's answer, you can use an editor template for Skill.  You will need to add a folder named `EditorTemplates` to your `Views\Controller` folder.  Now make a partial view in that folder named `Skill.cshtml` that looks something like this

```
@model Skill

@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.SkillName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Skills[i].Title)
// etc...
```

Now in your main view

```
using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateCart", "Orders"))
{

    @Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.Title)

    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.Skills)
}
```

Razor is smart enough that it will render each skill in `Skills` using the Skill.cshtml editor template.

Comment: i like this implementation

Comment: Can I just check where to put these files?  I've got a controller called "Skill" so I now have Views/Skill/EditorTemplates/Skills.cshtml.  The template doesn't appear to be included using the line @Html.EditorFor(p => p.Skills).  Are there any settings I might need to check (such as whether it's using Razor)?  Sorry if this is a bit of a newbie question!  And thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a lot of what seems like magic in MVC.  It will see that Skills is an `IEnumerable<Skill>`, so it will look for files in the EditorTemplates folder with either the name `Skill.cshtml` or with a `@model Skill`, I don't remember which.  Also, note that the file name should be `Skill.cshtml`, not `Skills.cshtml`.  I will update my answer.